# вставка переменной как часть mysql запроса в php

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно реализовать следующую задачу:
   `$query = "INSERT INTO таблица VALUES (раз, два, три) VALUES ('текст', {$words})";`
когда `$words = ' 'текст', 'еще текст' ';`

то есть требуется вставить часть mysql запроса из переменной, которая должна сразу заполнять несколько VALUES разделяя их запятыми и содержать одинарную кавычку.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вы какую библиотеку используете для отправки запросов?

Comment: Не совсем вас понял. Делаю это в простом .php файле

Comment: Обычно используют MySQLi http://phpclub.ru/detail/article/mysqli или PDO http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepared-statements.php. Вам нужны подготовленные выражения. Простой конкатенацией вставлять значения нельзя, т.к. пользователь может ввести что угодно. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0

Answer (score 1):

я так понимаю про ООП тут речи особой не идет?) напиши строковую переменную в которой будет часть твоего запроса и поставь ее. как то так:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `таблица` (`раз`, `два`, `три`) VALUES ('текст',". $words.")";
```

Но, конечно, так  себе решение, лучше почитай про PDO. Там есть подготовка переменных для вставки.

Comment: проблема в том, чтобы вставить в mysql запрос часть этого запроса, которая находится в переменной. а из-за того, что изначально в запросе не хватает полей (они находятся в переменной) мускул выдает ошибку

Comment: @Риад ну так подготовить же надо все от ниточки до ниточки

Answer (score 0):

Во первых, если ты вставляешь данные в БД из переменных, то как минимум их надо экранировать, используй `mysqli::escape_string()`.
Во вторых, сам запрос у тебя не верный

```
INSERT INTO таблица (раз, два, три) VALUES ('value1', 'value2', 'value3');
```

И в третих, переменная $words, ты не правильно используешь кавычки, попробуй так

```
$words = " 'текст', 'еще текст' ";
```

Comment: а если `$words = $teg1.', '.$teg2.', '.$teg3.', '.$teg4.', '.$teg5;` ?

Comment: Обычно в таблице известное число столбцов. И количество значений записывается одно и то же.

Comment: на выходе получается правильный запрос, количество значений и столбцов сходится, но все равно выдает эту ошибку

Comment: $query = 'INSERT INTO таблица (раз, два, три) VALUES ('",'", $tegs);

Comment: Какой запрос на выходе ?

Comment: INSERT INTO `таблица` (virtuemart_category_id, category_name, category_description, metadesc, metakey, tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4, tag5, customtitle, slug, tag6, tag7, tag8, tag9, tag10 ) VALUES ('', '1 3 5 7 9', 'текст', 'текст', '1 3 5 7 9', '2', '4', '6', '8', '10', 'текст', null, '', '', '', '', '')

Comment: и вот ошибка: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: $teg1.'&apos;, &apos;'.$teg2.'&apos;, &apos;'.$teg3.'&apos;, &apos;'.$teg4.'&apos;, &apos;'.$teg5; это $words

Comment: напрямую этот запрос из phpmyadmin срабатывает